# User is copy-pasting answers from ChatGPT

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Ethereum Stack Exchange post: [Why do nodes need to execute smart contract code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/why-do-nodes-need-to-execute-smart-contract-code)

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/148046/119144) is obviously generated by ChatGPT. You can actually copy paste my question into ChatGPT and get something extremely similar. Looking at other answers by the same user, they all look AI-generated, and OpenAI's [classifier](https://platform.openai.com/ai-text-classifier) ranks most as possibly AI-generated.

Comment: I'd noticed this as well...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: We should probably have an integration with ChatGPT to disallow users to just copy. Maybe even have AI answer first, and then if it's not sufficient, we will post just the question to the forum. But if AI can solve it, we should post the q&A.

Comment: I'm not guilty of what I'm being accused of here - see my answer below with proof that OP's classifier didn't even pick it up as a ChatGPT answer. I wrote my own answer based on my own research.

Answer (score 1):

I used ChatGPT once to answer a bounty question when it first came out - so why are you lying and spreading a false rumor that all my posts are copied when I used the classifier myself to put in the exact response you said was done using ChatGPT and surprise, surprise....it says it's unclear.

[image]

If you're going to accuse someone of plagarism....at least have some credible evidence. You won't find any because apart from the one time I posted what I believed was the answer to a question that had a bounty, I haven't used it to copy/paste answers like your accusing me of.

Oh - also, the moderator who deleted my post posted a ChatGPT response - the classifer said so - [EIP-4337 account abstraction and losing private keys](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/146865/eip-4337-account-abstraction-and-losing-private-keys/146878#146878)

[image]